# Is it possible to create multiple WebSockets in FireFox / Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, safari, websocket

I want to create two WebSocket Connections between Client and Server. The first connection is meant for sending plain Text for time critical applications to port 1337. The second connection should be used for secure data transfer by using tls on port 443. I'm using the following code to create the two WebSockets:

```
var ip  = document.URL.split("/")[2].split(":")[0];
var wss = new WebSocket("wss://" + ip + ":443"); //secure
var ws  = new WebSocket("ws://"  + ip + ":1337"); //realtime
```

Well, running this in Chrome and Opera works like a charm. But when I test this in FF it seems to establish the first (secure) connection and the aborts all code execution when it comes to the second one. In Safari I get an Error message that the server has closed the connection although it's still running. In both cases it downloads the html page and css etc. over https, but javascript execution fails at this point.

Has anyone an idea whats the problem here? As said, in Chrome and Opera everything works fine. I havent tested IE yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I now know whats the problem about this:

> WebSockets should not be used in a mixed content environment; that is, you shouldn't open a non-secure WebSocket connection from a page loaded using HTTPS or vice-versa. In fact, some browsers explicitly forbid this, including Firefox 8 and later.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Security_considerations

So it seems like I can't open two connections with different security level on one HTML page.